# Windows/Linux installer for Java program

Tags: java, deployment, installation

I have several Java applications. All of them have external jar dependencies and also require a couple of .dll/.so files to run. I want to build an installer for these applications, that will run properly just by double-clicking the installed program. What tools are available to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows [**Izpack**](http://izpack.org/) is good tool. Also [native implementation](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/izpack/) available.

But for Linux the best is to install it with a .sh script.

### Edit

The reason for this is that when you use a .sh script, you can check if java is installed and install it if it's not present. As I am aware- Izpack still lacks this feature.

Comment: lzpack claims to support linux as well, why do you still say that the best is to use a .sh script?

Answer (score 1):

> ..run properly just by double-clicking the installed program

This implies a rich client desktop app. rather than one based on the command line.  In that case, the best deployment technology is [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the **Oracle Corporation** technology used to launch rich client (Swing, AWT, SWT) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, **desktop integration,** file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), **partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform,** architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..